I can't run a pod after installing a cluster
I'm learning kubernetes and I installed kube cluster with kubeadm. and I wanted to install the counter pod. but I get the following error. can you help me ?
Events:
Type     Reason   Age                  From     Message

Warning  Failed   51m (x135 over 8h)   kubelet  (combined from similar events): Failed to pull image "busybox:1.28": failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/busybox:1.28": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/busybox:1.28": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/busybox/manifests/1.28": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:40971->127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout
Normal   BackOff  86s (x2172 over 8h)  kubelet  Back-off pulling image "busybox:1.28"

Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you post the pod yaml please? You can surround it in ``` backticks so it's properly formatted. The more context you provide the easier it will be for people to answer your question and the less chance your post will be downvoted (I'm not the one downvoting you, just giving a friendly tip )

The error indicates a DNS resolution issue preventing Kubelet from pulling the busybox:1.28 image. To resolve this, first, check that /etc/resolv.conf is correctly configured with a functional DNS server. Next, ensure your node has internet access and can reach registry-1.docker.io by testing the connection with curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/. Restart Kubelet using sudo systemctl restart kubelet to address any transient issues, and if your DNS server is local (127.0.0.53), try flushing the DNS cache or restarting the DNS service to restore proper DNS functionality.
